# php-pam : Depends: phpapi-20180731 but it is not installable

Tags: 20.04, php7

on Ubuntu Desktop 20.04 with PHP 7.4

apt install php-pam

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php-pam : Depends: phpapi-20180731 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.`

apt-cache policy php-pam
php-pam:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.0.3-1+deb10u1
  Version table:
     1.0.3-1+deb10u1 500
        500 http://packages.openmediavault.org/public usul/main amd64 Packages
```

I found a [proposal how to fix it for now obsolete PHP5](https://www.dokuwiki.org/auth:pam#ubuntu) only.

Any hint how this error can be fixed for PHP7?

Comment: Please add output of `apt-cache policy php-pam` to the question.

Comment: apt-cache policy php-pam
php-pam:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.0.3-1+deb10u1
  Version table:
     1.0.3-1+deb10u1 500
        500 http://packages.openmediavault.org/public usul/main amd64 Packages

Comment: Why do you have this repository added? Also please note that there is no php pam in [official repositories](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=php%20pam). Why do you need this package?

Comment: re Why? to install  OpenMediaVault (OMV) on Ubuntu. OMV documentation and forum posts mention "can install OpenMediavault on top of Debian, but not on top of Ubuntu" but give no reason. The reason now seems to be "there is no php pam in official Ubuntu repositories" hence OMVseems to have copied and modified  a working implementation of PAM interface. I was unable to find the reason for why Ubuntu chose to deviate from Debian in this aspect. Any hint how to overcome this issue greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

According to [OpenMediaVault docs → Installation on Debian](https://openmediavault.readthedocs.io/en/5.x/installation/on_debian.html?highlight=debian) you can install OpenMediavault on top of Debian, but not on top of Ubuntu.

I have tried to install it even on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS which is based on Debian Buster (10) and it does not work too.

Also note that `phpapi-20180731` is [a virtual package from Debian Buster](https://packages.debian.org/buster/phpapi-20180731), it does not exist in any Ubuntu version. The `php-pam` package [depends on it](http://packages.openmediavault.org/public/dists/usul/main/binary-amd64/Packages) and has origin in OpenMediaVault repository.

So you have to follow above guide using original Debian 10 netinstall.